# Working out probabilities of a singular instance and extrapolating to larger numbers

Tags: probability, problem-solving, extrapolation

I'm trying to work out out that if, for example, you were doing a test, and the chances of the test returning a false positive or false negative were worked out to be a specific percentage, say 20%, can that number then just simply be applied to the overall number of you did 1000 tests, or is it more advanced with that when probability comes into play?

For example, consider when they do seroprevalence tests for a virus in the community, such as Sars-Cov-2.

If the prevalence in the community is **5%** and the tests we are using have a:

- Positive predictive value (PPV) for sensitivity = **90%**, specificity = **99%**
- Negative predictive value (NPV) for sensitivity = **90%**, specificity = **99%**

With the above parameters this means that:

- The chance of a false positive is: 17.43%
- The chance of a false negative is: 0.53%

I am generating this data [here](https://epitools.ausvet.com.au/predictivevalues).

Now does that mean we can take this probability and use it as a whole as well? As in, if we test 1000 people, assuming the prevalence remains at 5%, and not accounting for false outcomes, let's say we get 50 positives and 950 negatives.

So does that mean we can easily calculate the expected number of false positives and negatives by simply using the expected rates above?

- `50 * 0.1743` = 8.715 false positives
- `980 * 0.0053` = 5.194 false negatives

Comment: When an event is independant of other event then you can not tell about the next even. It's like tossing a coin, all you can tell is that after N tosses the probabilty of head or tail is the same as for any other event, but the total heads is closer to $50$% as N grows.

Comment: I think the phrasing is ambiguous.  In statistical use, I'd say that the probability of a false negative was the conditional probability that you get a negative result given that you actually have the condition.  In informal use, I expect people might mean that it was the raw probability of a random test result being a false negative.  In any case, I have no idea what your computation might mean...it doesn't even use the $.23$ probability you stipulated.   Were you rounding it down for some reason?

Comment: @lulu I have edited my question and provided a far better example.

Comment: Yes, that's much better.  I have voted to reopen.

Comment: [here](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat507/lesson/10/10.3) is a simple guide to the various definitions you need.